# change css visibility state with inline javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a series of absolutely positioned images on a page that are all hidden using css: visibility.  And a menu that corresponds with these images.  Is there a way that I can change the visibility to visible onMouseover and back to hidden onMouseout?

```
<style type="text/css">
.class1 {visibility: hidden;}
.class2 {visibility: hidden;}
</style>

<ul>
   <li>Menu Item 1</li>
   <li>Menu Item 2</li>
</ul>

<img src="image1.jpg" class="class1" />
<img src="image2.jpg" class="class2" />
```

Any help is much appreciated!  I have to have this up by tomorrow :-\  Thanks in advance!

Comment: DO you use jQuery in your project or just pure JS ?

Comment: I believe there is a show/ hide function in css that may do what you want. Sorry I cant help more with this.

Comment: You need to describe exactly what you're trying to achieve here.  My answer assumed you meant mouseover/out of the menu items, while @user3126509 assumed you meant mouseover/out of the images themselves.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use jQuery.. bind mouseover to your li.. set the css.. and bind mouseout.

```
$('#num1').mouseover(function() {
    $('.class1').css('visibility', 'visible');
    $('#num1').mouseout(function() {
        $('.class1').css('visibility', 'hidden');
    });
});
```

I only did the first li and I took the easy way of assuming it'd have an id, but you get the idea.

[jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/YGLX2/1/)

Comment: You are the man!  This works exactly how I would have hoped it would!  Can I challenge you to make the .class1 item fade in? and fade out on mouseOut?  That would be super rad!

Comment: sure.  just change your css to use display:none instead of visibility:hidden and then you can just use fadeIn/fadeOut.  jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/YGLX2/5/

Answer (score 0):

When you hide an image, the height and width of it will not be present and you won't be able to hover it. use div.

See my example

[Fiddle - Click here](http://jsfiddle.net/ebXp5/)

html:

```
<div class="holder">
    <img src="http://dummy-images.com/abstract/dummy-160x120-Menu.jpg" class="img" />
</div>
<div class="holder">
    <img src="http://dummy-images.com/abstract/dummy-160x120-Menu.jpg" class="img" />
</div>
```

css:

```
.holder{
    width:160px;
    height:120px;
    background-color:blue;
}
.holder img{
    visibility:hidden;
}
.holder:hover img{
    visibility:visible;
}
```